# Representation of AC through vector

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Is there any difference if we use rms value or peak value of sinusoidal wave of AC in phasor (vector representation)?
i.e for the length of vector we are allowed to chose one of these,is there any difference or both have same meaning in case of vector?

Answer (score 0):

RMS value is chosen because it an AC quantity and the value changes continuously. The problem in choosing the Peak value is that it is an instantantaneous value and it becomes difficult to find out the values of all the other components in the circuits at the exact time.

If we choose the RMS value it is made equivalent to its DC value which is constant. The phasor drawn with RMS will be the same at all conditions. But If you draw the phasor with the peak value which is instantaneous value the phasor will change as soon as the $\omega$
changes

Comment: but as the angular frequency is constant...so arent v r wrong that v r replacing the peak value and rms value